# What does 'L' mean in the name of motor driver IC "L293D"?

Tags: motor, driver

i was wondering what the letter L in the name L293D stand for and what does it mean.

Comment: Nothing to do with electronic design. Question should be closed.

Comment: @leon how does understanding what an electronic part's part number mean have nothing to do with electronic design...

Comment: Have to agree with @Passerby here- the suffixes in part numbers mean something and *sometimes* the prefixes mean something (eg. SN74xxx vs. SN54xxx indicates commercial vs. military temperature range) so I'm not sure how one would know.

Comment: There is no standard in part numbering, and it can be inconsistent even within a single company. So the question essentially is a one off for a single part for a single company that may have no actual meaning anymore.

Comment: @jarrod some questions are objectively more valuable, but that doesn't make them off topic. It's good to know the history at times.

Answer (score 8):

Not much. It's just a part number, originally from the European company SGS-Ates.

Perhaps at one time it indicated "Linear" (most of the chips SGS made were bipolar linear and started with an L or an T). With all the mergers over the years, any such meaning would be long gone from those 30-40 year old designs.

When SGS made clones of then-popular parts such as the \$\mu\$A7805 and \$\mu\$A709A they called them L7805 and L709A so you could say it's kind of a marker that points out the manufacturer (SGS-Ates, then SGS-Thomson, now ST).